# Cloud firestore exceptions not caught by except block

Tags: python, firebase, exception, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

```
import datetime
from threading import Timer
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore
import calendar

db = firestore.Client()
col_ref = db.collection(u'tblAssgin').get()
current_serving = [doc.id for doc in col_ref]
#print(current_serving)

def sit_time():

    for i in current_serving:
        try:
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'tblAssgin').document(i)
        except:
            current_serving.remove(doc_ref)
        else:
            doc = doc_ref.get()
            a = doc.get('assginTime')
            assign_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(a.timetuple()))
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            sitting_time = now - assign_time
            hours,remainder = divmod(sitting_time.seconds, 3600)
            minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
            print('minutes:',minutes)
            updates = {u'sitting_time':minutes}
            doc_ref.update(updates)

t = None

def refresh():
    global t
    sit_time()
    t = Timer(60, refresh)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

refresh()
```

So basically the above code does that it first fetches all the document id's of collection name 'tblAssgin' and store it in 'current_serving' list. Then, loops over each document and calculate time and runs again after every 60 sec. Now suppose I delete one document then that document will not be found. So I want to do that when the document is not found exception is raised and that document id gets's removed from  'current_serving' list. But the exception is not caught.

Please help

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming [`CollectionReference.document()`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/firestore/collection.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.collection.CollectionReference.document) will throw an exception if the document does not exist. It doesn't.

```
>>> client.collection('non-existing').document('also-non-existing')
<google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentReference object at 0x10feac208>
```

But `DocumentReference.get()` will throw an exception if the document doesn't exist.

```
>>> client.collection('non-existing').document('also-non-existing').get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/gae/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/document.py", line 432, in get
    raise exceptions.NotFound(self._document_path)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 ~/databases/(default)/documents/non-existing/also-non-existing
```

Comment: I got your point but still couldn't figure out the changes that need to be made in the code. Actually, I'm new to these so if you could please illustrate your concept in my code.

Comment: You need `doc_ref = db.collection(u'tblAssgin').document(i).get()`